# Is there a difference between playing as "Sir" or playing as "Madam"

Tags: sir-you-are-being-hunted

The title screen of *Sir, you are being hunted* allows you to switch between playing as *Sir* and playing as *Madam*. Does this setting have any effect on the game?

Comment: I don't have the game so I can't check, but maybe view model/player model and some sounds/dialogue change or are supposed to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It changes the menu title and the voiceovers - nothing else (so far).

The player doesn't have a model yet (but it will have by the time multiplayer releases!). This will reflect the selected gender...